# How to post on own facebook page

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post image as my Page on(Like fan Page)

I am using this but it post with user post on Page but I want as My page Post.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, "Page_ID"+"/photos"
            , null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    if(response.getError()==null) {


                        Toast.makeText(FacebookShareActivity.this, "Shared on facebook page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(FacebookShareActivity.this, "Error while sharing on facebook page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

            });


    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    params.putByteArray("object_attachment",byteArray);
    params.putString("description", "Image");
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Page Token instead of a User Token, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish

> A page access token with publish_pages permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanku Sir I used this and response 
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Parameter object_attachment: Invalid id: {}}}

Comment: How to get the Page token?

Comment: i´ve added some links about that in my answer

Comment: Thankyou I use Page Token